# Auto logout in condition odoo 10

Tags: python, session, odoo-10

i had a problem when i was try to make the auto logout in odoo 10. I was created change password page, after change password, i want end session and back to login page again. But the result never land me to teh login page. Here my code :

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(MyPass, self).create(vals)

    get_new_passwd = vals['new_password']
    get_conf_passwd = vals['confirm_pwd']

    if get_conf_passwd != get_new_passwd:
        raise ValidationError ("Pass")

    hashing_pass = CryptContext(['pbkdf2_sha512']).encrypt(get_new_passwd)

    data_users = self.env['res.users'].browse(self.env.uid)


    data_users.write({'password_crypt': hashing_pass})
    request.session.logout(keep_db=True
```

I found the solution.

```
def check(self, **kw):
    get_re_users = request.env.user
    error = {}
    if get_re_users.passwd_changed:
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web')
    else:
        if request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
            get_new_passwd = http.request.params['new_password']
            get_conf_passwd = http.request.params['confirm_pwd']

            session = http.request.session

            hashing_pass = CryptContext(['pbkdf2_sha512']).encrypt(get_new_passwd)

            data_users = http.request.env['res.users'].sudo().browse(http.request.env.uid)

            data_users.write({'password_crypt': hashing_pass, "passwd_changed":True, "name":get_username_odoo, "login":get_name_login})

            if session.db and session.uid:
                session.logout(keep_db=True)
                # return {
                #   'type' : 'ir.actions.act_url',
                #   'url': '/web',
                #   'target': 'self',
                # }
                return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/login')

        return http.request.render('name_model.id_view')
```

Comment: Nice try.If you found the solution, pls post it@Stefani

Comment: @Naveen I founf the solution, check the question. I was update my code.